# How do I get rid of the straight line from the first and last point?

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

How do I get rid of the straight line from the first and last points? Why aren't the lines colored? Is there a better way to make a line plot, I get a similar problem with ggplot2.

```
dat<-Data_for_Analysis_1_

dat$Enrichment<-factor(dat$Enrichment)

plot(TF~Minute, data=dat, col=Enrichment, pch=20,xlab="Minute", 
     ylab="No. of Tongue Flicks", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
     cex.main=1.5, cex.sub=1.6)
lines(TF~Minute, data=dat, col=Enrichment)
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HHlB.png]

Comment: For the line color,  you need `col=dat$Enrichment`

Comment: @G5W That actually does *not* appear to be needed, I would have thought so to.

Comment: You could use the group option: `ggplot(dat, aes(x=Minute, y=TF, group=Enrichment, col=Enrichment)) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(y="No. of Tongue Flicks")`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data looks like the toy data I create below, the following should do it:

```
# Create some toy data
m <- 10
dat <- data.frame(Minute = rep(0:60, m))
dat$Enrichment <- rep(LETTERS[1:m], each = 61)
dat$TF <- c(replicate(m, cumsum(rnorm(61, mean = 0.3))))
head(dat)  
#  Minute Enrichment         TF
#1      0          A  0.3203584
#2      1          A  0.9571599
#3      2          A  1.5361236
#4      3          A  1.7571507
#  ... 
#60     59         A  19.25409068
#61     60         A  20.68664549
#62      0         B  -0.05674056
#63      1         B  0.64608473
## And so on...

# Your code:
dat$Enrichment <- factor(dat$Enrichment)

plot(TF ~ Minute, data=dat, col=Enrichment, pch=20,xlab="Minute", 
     ylab="No. of Tongue Flicks", cex.lab=1.5, cex.axis=1.5, 
     cex.main=1.5, cex.sub = 1.6)

# Draw line for each group (could also be done with a for-loop)
.tmp <- lapply(split(dat, dat$Enrichment), 
               function(d) lines(TF ~ Minute, data=d, col=Enrichment))
```

[image: output]

I suspect your problem is that the time and `TF` vectors you pass to `lines` is interpreted as two long unbroken vectors of values. As such, it "resets" after each new group as the your code basically ignores your the grouping variable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

You didn't answer my question directly but you informed me about the group function.

I went to excel and made another column labeled "Instance" where each individual observation was labelled as 1, 2 ,3 etc and then grouped the data by that.

`ggplot(dat, aes(x=Minute, y=TF, group=Instance , col=Enrichment)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + labs(y="No. of Tongue Flicks")`

Just got to give it a more appropriate Key.

Thanks again, the replies are really fast and extensive.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iRpl.png)